# Is it possible to serve both "proxied content" and local files from the same domain using Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a Nginx server configured as a reverse-proxy cache server to a remote Apache server. At this point, all is running fine. Here's a part of my configuration (I've left some irrelevant parts out):

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.mywebsite.com mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://123.123.123.123;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Vary;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_cache_revalidate off;
        proxy_next_upstream off;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_bypass $bypass $do_not_cache;
        proxy_no_cache $do_not_cache;
        proxy_cache_valid any 2880m;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }   
}
```

Now what I want to do is to serve files from a specific directory from local files stored on the Nginx server. The rest of the content must still be cached from the source server:

- //www.mywebsite.com => Serves cached content from //123.123.123.123
- //www.mywebsite.com/local => Serves files stored locally on the Nginx server

Is it possible to include another location in the "server" section of the configuration? I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
location /local/ {
    root /home/user/public_html/local;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
}
```

Sorry for my english by the way.

Comment: please flag the answer as accepted if you've solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right way, you should define another [`location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) with an [`alias`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive:

```
location /local/ {
    alias /home/user/public_html/local;
}
```

Now, when you request the `http://YOUR_DOMAIN/local/page.html`, it will serve `/home/user/public_html/local/page.html`.

Keep in mind that nginx must have read permission in the specified root directory.

Read [this for the subtle difference between root and alias](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,129656,130107#msg-130107) directives.

Comment: Actually that was pretty close but "root" needs to be changed to "alias":

Comment: Thank you @StephaneBrault, now you can accept it to